# Is is possible to create instance of child class from parent class?

Tags: ruby, inheritance

I try to define operational semantics in Ruby, just for learning purposes. And I'd like to define operations like: add, multiply, subtraction, division.

Here is code:

```
class Operation < Struct.new(:left, :right)
  def inspect
    "#{self}"
  end

  def reducible?
    true
  end 
end

class Add < Operation
  def to_s
    "#{left} + #{right}"
  end

  def reduce
    if left.reducible?
      Add.new(left.reduce, right)
    elsif right.reducible?
      Add.new(left, right.reduce)
    else
      Number.new(left.value + right.value)
    end
  end

end

class Multiply < Operation
  def to_s
    "#{left} * #{right}"
  end

   def reduce
    if left.reducible?
      Multiply.new(left.reduce, right)
    elsif right.reducible?
      Multiply.new(left, right.reduce)
    else
      Number.new(left.value + right.value)
    end
  end
end
```

Is it possible to have the same thing, but define `reduce` in `Operation` class, but create instance of some particular child class in `Operation` class?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

```
class Operation
  def reduce
    if left.reducible?
      self.class.new(left.reduce, right)
    elsif right.reducible?
      self.class.new(left, right.reduce)
    else
      Number.new(left.value + right.value)
    end
  end
end
```